# custom xml angled button

Tags: android, xml, button, shapes

I am trying to create two buttons, like these

[image: how I want the buttons]

but not with photoshop.

I know I can create shapes like this:
    `android:shape="...."`

But I don't know how to create ones like the image above.

Any help would be great

**edit:**
I have it as an oval, but don't know how to change the shape any further:

The XML:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#302226"
        android:endColor="#6D7B8D"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="6dp"
        android:top="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:bottom="6dp" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I edited my question to include what I've been trying to change. I'm just wondering is there code to change angles of individual sides?